# Pandas. Разбить период посуточно с учетом времени

Tags: python, pandas

Всем добрый день!

Есть датафрейм со столбцами даты начала и даты окончания.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочется получить строку для каждого дня из этого диапазона, как в примере ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бывает такое, что datefrom и datetill в рамках одного дня будут.

Код для изначального датафрейма.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datefrom': ['01.01.2023 13:00'],
    'datetill': ['01.03.2023 15:00']
}).astype({'datefrom': 'datetime64', 'datetill': 'datetime64'})
```

Всем откликнувшимся спасибо!

Comment: а если datefrom и datetill не в пределах одного дня, то какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Если не в пределах одного дня, то такой как на скриншоте. Дробим период на дни, для первой строки дата начала будет равна исходному datefrom - 01.01.2023 13:00, дата окончания - последняя секунда этого дня 01.01.2023 23:59:59. Для второго дня дата начала - минимальная секунда этого дня 02.01.2023 00:00:00, дата окончания - максимальная секунда данного дня - 02.01.2023 23:59:59. Для третьего дня соответственно 03.01.2023 00:00:00 и 03.03.2023 15:00. Если datefrom и datetill в рамках одного дня, то по сути остается строка как она есть.

Answer (score 2):

Создаем фрейм с днями с помощью `date_range`, сбрасывая время на 0 через параметр `normalize`, затем копируем колонку `date` в `datefrom`. Потом создаем колонку `datetill` как `datefrom` + 1 день - 1 секунда - это и будет 59:59. В конце заменяем первое в `datefrom` и последнее в `datetill` значения на дату/время из df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datefrom': ['01.01.2023 13:00'],
    'datetill': ['01.03.2023 15:00']
}).astype({'datefrom': 'datetime64', 'datetill': 'datetime64'})

dfrom, dtill = df.at[0, 'datefrom'], df.at[0, 'datetill']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(dfrom, dtill, freq='D', normalize=True)}).assign(datefrom=lambda x: x['date'])
df1['datetill'] = df1.datefrom + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d') - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='s')
df1.at[df1.iloc[0].name, 'datefrom'], df1.at[df1.iloc[-1].name, 'datetill'] = dfrom, dtill

print(df)
print(df1)
```

```
             datefrom            datetill
0 2023-01-01 13:00:00 2023-01-03 15:00:00
        date            datefrom            datetill
0 2023-01-01 2023-01-01 13:00:00 2023-01-01 23:59:59
1 2023-01-02 2023-01-02 00:00:00 2023-01-02 23:59:59
2 2023-01-03 2023-01-03 00:00:00 2023-01-03 15:00:00
```

Comment: pd.date_range имеет параметр normalize

Comment: @strawdog спасибо! поправил

Answer (score 1):

я в общем-то использовал похожий инструментарий, что и @Алексей Р:

```
df["ranges"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x["datefrom"], end=x["datetill"], freq="D", normalize=True), axis=1)
df = df.explode("ranges")

df.loc[df["datefrom"].dt.date != df["ranges"],"datefrom"] = df.loc[df["datefrom"].dt.date != df["ranges"],"ranges"]
df.loc[df["datetill"].dt.date != df["ranges"],"datetill"] = df.loc[df["datetill"].dt.date != df["ranges"],"ranges"]+pd.Timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59)
```

df:

```
             datefrom            datetill     ranges
0 2023-01-01 13:00:00 2023-01-01 23:59:00 2023-01-01
0 2023-01-02 00:00:00 2023-01-02 23:59:00 2023-01-02
0 2023-01-03 00:00:00 2023-01-03 15:00:00 2023-01-03
1 2023-01-04 13:00:00 2023-01-04 18:00:00 2023-01-04
```

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, спасибо! Разберу все варианты предложенные :-)

Выложу как я решил, нубский вариант:

```
df['date']=[pd.date_range(x , y , normalize=True ) for x , y in zip(df.datefrom, df.datetill)]
df=df.explode('date')
df = df.loc[:, ['date', 'datefrom', 'datetill']]
df = df.dropna(subset=['date'])
df['date_2'] =df[['date', 'datefrom']].max(axis=1)
df['date_3'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str) + ' ' + str(time(23,59,59)))
df['date_4'] = df[['date_3', 'datetill']].min(axis=1)
df = df[['date', 'date_2', 'date_4']]
df = df.rename(columns={'date_2': 'datefrom', 'date_4': 'datetill'})
```